# Выборка максимального значения из дублирующих строк

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Структура таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В таблице есть записи, которые могут дублироваться по полю code.
Так же у этих записей есть колонка deleted_date, по которой определяется время удаленной записи.

Не получается выбрать те записи, которые сгруппированы по одному коду + у которых в колонке deleted стоит значение 1 + для которых в колонке deleted_date стоит максимальное значение.
Я сделал запрос:

```
SELECT id 
  FROM analyzes 
 WHERE code IN 
       (SELECT code 
          FROM analyzes 
         WHERE deleted = 1 
         GROUP BY code 
        HAVING count(code)>1)
```

Но он работает не правильно.
Подскажите пожалуйста, у кого много опыта в sql, возможно ли с помощью sql сделать данный запрос?

Comment: Не легче в этом поле хранить дату и выбирать уже по ней?

Comment: Без разницы, можно и дату хранить, но как сделать запрос, чтобы возвращать записи с максимальными датами

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что вам надо найти последние удаленные записи?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT code, deleted, MAX(deleted_date) FROM analyzes WHERE deleted = 1 GROUP BY code, deleted;
```

Comment: Немного не так. Нужно выбрать айдишники записей, где код 01.00.007 не должен попадать, потому что есть запись с таким же кодом, у которой deleted = 0. http://joxi.ru/LmGLwQOteZRxK2

Comment: В этом случае достаточно добавить - AND code NOT IN (SELECT code FROM analyzes WHERE deleted = 0)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, code, deleted_date 
FROM   analyzes t
WHERE  deleted = 1
AND    deleted_date = 
       (select max(deleted_date) 
        from   analyzes a
        where  t.code = a.code
        group  by a.code
        having min(a.deleted) = 1)
```

Comment: Немного не так. Записи с кодом 01.00.007 не должны попадать, потому что есть запись точно с таким же кодом, у которой deleted = 0. http://joxi.ru/J2bRwEdcXM4dW2  http://joxi.ru/LmGLwQOteZRxK2

Comment: @tirael8 тогда так. Вы хоть попробуйте чуть чуть разобраться в происходящем

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> create table `analyzes`
> (
>   `id` int,
>   `code` varchar(10),
>   `deleted` int, 
>   `deleted_date` int
> );
> ```

> ```
> insert into `analyzes` (`id`,`code`,`deleted`,`deleted_date`) values
> ( 1,'01.00.002',1,1),
> ( 2,'01.00.002',1,2),
> (15,'01.00.002',1,3),
> ( 3,'01.00.005',1,2),
> (17,'01.00.005',1,1),
> (16,'01.00.006',0,1),
> (18,'01.00.007',1,1),
> (19,'01.00.007',0,2);
> ```

> ```
> select * from `analyzes`;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | code      | deleted | deleted_date
> -: | :-------- | ------: | -----------:
>  1 | 01.00.002 |       1 |            1
>  2 | 01.00.002 |       1 |            2
> 15 | 01.00.002 |       1 |            3
>  3 | 01.00.005 |       1 |            2
> 17 | 01.00.005 |       1 |            1
> 16 | 01.00.006 |       0 |            1
> 18 | 01.00.007 |       1 |            1
> 19 | 01.00.007 |       0 |            2
> ```

> ```
> with `t1` as (
>   with `t0` as (
>     select
>       `id`,
>       `code`,
>       `deleted_date` ,
>       max(`deleted_date`) over(partition by `code` order by `code`) `deleted_date_max`
>     from `analyzes`
>     where 
>       `deleted` = 1
>   )
>   select 
>     `id`,
>     `code`,
>     `deleted_date`
>   from `t0` 
>   where `deleted_date` = `deleted_date_max`
> ),
> `t2` as (
>   select
>     `code`
>   from `analyzes`
>   where `deleted` = 0
> )
> select 
>   `t1`.`id`
> from `t1`
>   left join `t2` on `t1`.`code` = `t2`.`code`
> where 
>   `t2`. `code` is null
> ```
>
> ```
> | id |
> | -- |
> | 15 |
> |  3 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=534848d5040556e219333341c5d9c121)*